# Jest no reconoce require("axios").default

Tags: javascript, nodejs, axios, jestjs

Hola estoy trantando de testear una api con una llamada tipo get donde creo una instancia de axios, con axios.create. Y cuando importo la función que devuelve el get en el test de jest me da este error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

   6 |
   7 | const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json; 
charset=utf-8" };
>  8 | const instance = axios.create({
```

Y este es mi código en el test:

```
const { getItemsFromApi } = require("./../api");

describe("Items api test", () => {

it("Get items from appi", async () => {});
});
```

Esta es la api:

```
//Aquí es el problema
const axios = require("axios").default;

const headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" };
const instance = axios.create({
baseURL: process.env.xxx,
 headers: headers,
});

const getItemsFromApi = async () => {
try {
const resp = await instance.get("/items");
if (resp.status === 200) {
  //console.log(resp.data);
  return resp.data;
} else {
}
} catch (error) {
console.error(error);
}
};
```

Comment: Porque incluyes el default?

Comment: Hola Paulo ya lo quite siguio el error pero agregué un moock para axios y todo bien

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucioné el problema. con estos pasos.

1. quite el default de axios.
2. cree un fichero dentro de una carpeta **mocks** con este contenido.

   ```
   const axios = {
   get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
   post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: {} })),
   create: () => axios,
   defaults: {
   adapter: {},
   },
   };

   module.exports = axios;
   ```